# How to select form using Mechanize based on the fields it has?

Tags: ruby, forms, web-scraping, screen-scraping, mechanize

I am using Mechanize to do some simple web scraping.

In a webpage, I have several forms and the forms do not have id or name.

The only way I know how to differentiate the forms is by the hidden input field which has the name `a`.

How do I use this as a criteria to select the correct form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try manual selection:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('http://somesite.com/')
forms = page.forms.select {|form| form.fields.any? {|field| field.name == 'a' && field.type == 'hidden'}}
form = forms[0] unless forms == []
```

Comment: `form = page.forms.find {|form| form.fields.any? {|field| field.name == 'a' && field.type == 'hidden'}}`

Then you don't need the last line.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Form#has_field?` like so:

```
form = page.forms.find{|f| f.has_field? 'a'}
```